# Native Query Mapping on the fly openJPA

Tags: orm, openjpa

I am wondering if it is possible to map a named native query on the fly instead of getting back a list of Object[] and then looping through and setting up the object that way.  I have a call which I know ill return a massive data set and I want to be able to map it right to my entity.  Can I do that or will I have to continue looping through the result set.

Here is what I am doing now...

```
List<Provider> ObjList = (List<Provider>) emf.createNativeQuery(assembleQuery(organizationIDs, 5)).getResultList();
```

That is my entity, the List (my entity is the provider).  Normally I would just return a `List<Object[]>`
and then I would loop through that to get back all the objects and set them up as new providers and add them to a list....

```
//List<Provider> provList = new ArrayList<Provider>(); 
/*for(Object[] obj: ObjList)
{
    provList.add(this.GetProviderFromObj(obj));
}*/
```

As you can see I commented that section of the code out to try this out.  I know you can map named native queries if you put your native query in the entity itself and then call it via createNamedQuery.  I would do it that way, but I need to use the `IN` oracle keyword because I have a list of ID's that I want to check against.  It is not just one that is needed.  And as we all know, native queruies don't handle the `in` keyword to well.  Any advice?

Sigh, If only the IN keyword was supported well for NamedNativeQueries.

Comment: I'm a bit confused by your question.  Are you asking if there's a way to have OpenJPA directly return a list of Provider objects when you call createNativeQuery(...).getResultList() so you don't have to manually convert the Objects to Providers?

Comment: Yep.  I figured it out.  You need to set a named mapping and then you call that when you call your native query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that Provider is configured as a JPA entity, you should be able to specify the class as the second parameter to your createNativeQuery call.  For example:

```
List<Provider> ObjList = (List<Provider>) emf.createNativeQuery(assembleQuery(organizationIDs, 5), Provider.class).getResultList();
```

According to the documentation, "At a minimum, your SQL must select the class' primary key columns, discriminator column (if mapped), and version column (also if mapped)."

See the [OpenJPA documentation](http://openjpa.apache.org/docs/latest/jpa_overview_sqlquery_obj.html) for more details.